# Cos'è una "persiana in libro"?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *L'isola*, di Giani Stuparich, ho letto:

> La stanza era ancora piena di fumo, che usciva a pigre volute dalla finestra con le **persiane in libro**; sul tavolo il portacenere colmo di mozziconi e di fiammiferi bruciati e, accanto, in una scatola di latta erano, ben ordinate, le lenze nuove, di crino nero avvolto intorno ai sugheri, su cui eran puntati gli ami lucenti: c'era qualche vuoto, forse il posto di quelle che suo padre aveva scelte e s'era portate con sé.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "persiane in libro"? Ho cercato alle voci "persiana" e "libro" di parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato questa locuzione.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sono sicuro che si tratti di una persiana con un'apertura a libro, ovvero che si ripiega su se stessa, tipo queste

http://www.stabileserramenti.it/prodotti/img/38_persiane_con_apertura_a_libro.jpg

http://www.stabileserramenti.it/prodotti/img/58_persiane_con_apertura_a_libro_2.jpg

https://www.fintecnic.eu/wgrane-pliki/mini_persiane-pieghevoli-richiudibili.jpg